# mysql_query(INSERT ...) function not working in my code

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, phpmyadmin

I've create database, which basically accept name and Id and answer string of 
length 47,and my php code will grade the incoming results against the answer key I provided and number containing the count of correct answers will stored in database. this is information of my database.
database name is marking
and table called 'answer', which has 5 fields as follow

```
1) answer_id :int , not null, auto increament.
2) name: text
3)id : text
4)answers : text
5)correct : int
```

my question and problem is the function is working

```
// setup query
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `answer` VALUES 
 (NULL,'$name', '$id','$answers','$correct')");
// run query
$result = mysql_query($q);
```

or in another way , nothing storing in my database ???

Thanks in advance.

this is the whole program.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
// to turn error reporting off 
error_reporting(0);

$name  =$_POST['name']; 
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$answers = $_POST['answers'];

// check the length of string
if(strlen($answers) !=10) 
{
print'your answer string must be 10';

return;

} 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("marking"); 
$name = addslashes($name); 
$id = addslashes($id); 
$answers =  addslashes($answers); 
$answer_key =  "abcfdbbjca"; 
$correct =  0; 
for($i=0;$i<strlen($answer_key);$i++) 
{

if($answer_key[$i]  == $answers[$i])

$correct++;

} 
 //  Setup query
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `answer` VALUES ('$name', '$id','$answers','$correct')");
$result = mysql_query($q);
print 'Thnak you. You got' + $correct + 'of 10 answers correct'; 
?>
```

Comment: it looks like you are trying to store a NULL value in your answer_id which can't be null.

Comment: There are numerous reasons this may fail. First you must debug it.  `if (!$result) {echo mysql_error();}` to verify syntax errors. If your input values are not escaped properly, quotes may break it too.

Comment: you may need to provide more info for anyone to know. But for starters you are calling mysql_query twice there. Once on a result. We would need to know the values of these vars, if you're connected, any mysql_error results, etc. Also, someone will yell at you for using mysql_functions instead of mysqli or pdo

Comment: @nathanhayfield That's OK. It's an auto increment field, assigning NULL means that it should get its automatic increment value.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, I usually just leave it out altogether. Never tried it that way.

Comment: There's no separate "setup query" and "run query" steps when using the mysql_XXX functions.

Comment: @nathanhayfield But that requires putting a list of column names in the INSERT statement. If you leave the column names out, you have to supply values for all columns, and must specify NULL for the autoincrement.

Comment: @Barmar & nathanhayfield: both are correct: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: $q = "INSERT... is enough if you want to setup your query string before running it, like DC_ fied it in his answer

Comment: I didn't get any error, everything works fine but when I check my database nothing is there... and I've tried 
mysql_query("insert into answer values('$name','$id','$answer',$correct)");  still same result nothing added to my database.

Comment: did you try to run the full parsed query directly on your database (replacing $.. by the real values)

Comment: I posted my whole program could anyone please check whats the problem is and pointed me where and what I need to edit to make it work.

Comment: Could you post some examples of what `$answers` could hold? Both good and bad values. What bothers me is the validation `if(strlen($answers) !=10)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// setup query
$q = "INSERT INTO `answer` (`name`, `id`, `answers`, `correct`) VALUES 
 ('$name', '$id','$answers','$correct')";

//Run Query
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, you should avoid using `mysql_` functions as they are in the process of being deprecated. Instead, I recommend you familiarize yourself with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Also, note, the `or die(mysql_error())` portion should not be used in production code, only for debugging purposes.

Comment: I like doing it this style. If you're having a problem, you can easily insert `echo $q` into the script to make sure it's correct.

Comment: No DC, unfortunately no error but it's always everything is compiling correctly and when i press submit it's always printing 'your answer string must be 10' even if your string is 10 and the most importantly nothing is storing in table 'answer' in my database

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

You are actually executing the query twice. `mysql_query` executes the query and returns the result resource. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

And also, you are quoting the `int` column `correct` in your query, as far as I know, you can't do that (I could be wrong there).

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `answer` VALUES (NULL,'$name', '$id','$answers',$correct)");
```

**EDIT:** Turns out I'm actually wrong, you may disregard my answer.

Comment: There's no harm in quoting an int field. It will be converted automatically.

Comment: Alright, then I really am wrong there, I wasn't 100% sure about that.

Comment: I posted my whole program could anyone please check whats the problem is and pointed me where and what I need to edit to make it work.

Comment: Refer to my comment in your OP, I'm willing to help you, but we need more clarifications.